# Avançando datas com Local Date

Tags: java, data

Estou tentando fazer com que a data que o usuário insira no construtor seja avançada em 1 dia.

Porém não estou obtendo o resultado esperado, está sendo retornado o mesmo dia. Tentei verificar pelo debug e simplesmente o `plusDays()` não soma 1 dia. Provavelmente estou fazendo algo errado, podem me ajudar?

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Data {
    private Integer dia;
    private Integer mes;
    private Integer ano;

    private LocalDate dataHoje;


    public Data(Integer dia, Integer mes, Integer ano) {

        if(dia > 31 || dia <= 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Não existem dias nulos, nem dias maiores que 31!");

        } else {
            setDia(dia);
        }

        if (mes > 12) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Só existem 12 meses!");

        } else if (mes <= 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Não podem existir meses negativos ou nulos!");

        }else {
            setMes(mes);
        }


        if(ano < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Não trabalhamos com anos A.C! Insira um D.C");  
        } else {            
            setAno(ano);
        }

        this.dataHoje = LocalDate.of(ano, mes, dia);
    }


    public Data() {
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        System.out.println("A Data de hoje é : " + now.format(formatter));
    }


    public String getDataInserida() {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        return dataHoje.format(formatter);
    }



    public LocalDate avancarDia() {
        dataHoje.plusDays(1);
        return dataHoje;
    }
// aqui em baixo ficam os getters e setters dos atributos primitivos

}
```

Está é minha classe app.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Data dataSistema = new Data();
        Data data = new Data(8,12,1998);

        System.out.println(data.getDataInserida());

        data.avancarDia();

        System.out.println(data.getDataInserida());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As classes do `java.time` são [imutáveis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/design.html), e métodos como [`plusDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays-long-) retornam **outra instância** com os valores modificados. Ou seja, se você só fizer:

```
dataHoje.plusDays(1);
```

O retorno do método é ignorado (pois não é atribuído para nenhuma variável), e `dataHoje` continua com o mesmo valor original.

Então você deveria fazer:

```
public LocalDate avancarDia() {
    dataHoje = dataHoje.plusDays(1);
    return dataHoje;
}
```

Com isso, o valor de `dataHoje` é atualizado para o dia seguinte.

Comment: Sim, desculpa, eu alterei para plusDay, mas esqueci de alterar aqui. Sua solução funcionou, muito obrigado, não sabia que eles eram imutáveis.

Comment: Sério, muito obrigado mesmo amigo, estou aprendendo java agora, por isso a dificuldade com as datas, muito obrigado!

Comment: @Bussola Pois é, a imutabilidade vale para todas as classes do `java.time`. Eu tb já cometi esse mesmo erro na primeira vez que usei essa API :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Tenta assim

```
    LocalDate hoje = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate amanha = hoje.plusDays(1);
    System.out.println(amanha);
```

Comment: Então, no caso essa tá retornando a data do sistema e avançando ela, eu queria avançar aquela data que o cara passou no construtor, retornar dia 09/12/1998