# Imprimir mês atual e os próximos dois meses

Tags: java, data, simpledateformat

Estou pegando o mês atual em número e preciso incrementar ele em mais dois meses adiante, além de utilizar o mês atual e salvar em um array de string.

Estou pegando o inteiro e recuperando o nome do mês, porém mesmo pegando números diferentes de 12, ele insiste em escrever `"DEZ"`. Alguém sabe um outro método de recuperar o mês escrito por extenso?

Segue o trecho de código:

```
int mes = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeMeses; i++) {
   Locale local = new Locale("pt", "BR");
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", local);
   axisData[i] = dateFormat.format(mes + i).toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer somar meses a um [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), use o [método `add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add-int-int-), informando o campo que você quer somar (no caso, como quero somar o mês, uso [`Calendar.MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int quantidadeMeses = 3;
Locale local = new Locale("pt", "BR");
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", local);
for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeMeses; i++) {
    // imprime a data correspondente ao Calendar
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()).toUpperCase());
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1); // soma 1 mês
}
```

No caso acima, o `Calendar` começa com a data de hoje (setembro), e dentro do `for` eu imprimo a data e depois somo 1 mês. O resultado é:

```
SET
OUT
NOV
```

Repare também que você não precisa criar o `SimpleDateFormat` dentro do `for`, basta criá-lo uma vez antes do *loop* e reutilizá-lo a cada iteração.

Além disso, eu uso o [método `getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--), que retorna um [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), para que este seja passado para o [método `format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-).

---

#### `java.time`

Se estiver usando Java >= 8 **e** seu código não depende do uso de [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) e [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), uma alternativa é usar a [API `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), que é mais moderna e resolve muitos dos [problemas da API antiga](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442).

No seu caso, você poderia usar um [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) para guardar a data, usar o [método `plusMonths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths-long-) para somar meses, e formatar a data com um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
LocalDate data = LocalDate.now();
int quantidadeMeses = 3;
Locale local = new Locale("pt", "BR");
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM", local);
for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeMeses; i++) {
    System.out.println(fmt.format(data).toUpperCase());
    data = data.plusMonths(1); // somar 1 mês
}
```

Repare que ao somar 1 mês eu tive que atribuir o retorno para a variável `data`. Isso acontece porque [as classes do `java.time` são imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/387806/112052), e métodos como `plusMonths` sempre retornam outra instância com os valores modificados. A saída é a mesma do código com `Calendar`.

Como o `java.time` possui [várias classes diferentes para representar datas e horas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html), você também pode optar por usar outras delas, dependendo do que você precisa.

Neste caso, se você não precisa da data exata (dia, mês e ano), poderia usar um [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html), que é uma classe que guarda apenas o mês e ano. Seu funcionamento é bem similar a `LocalDate`, pois ela também possui o [método `plusMonths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#plusMonths-long-):

```
YearMonth data = YearMonth.now();
int quantidadeMeses = 3;
Locale local = new Locale("pt", "BR");
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM", local);
for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeMeses; i++) {
    System.out.println(fmt.format(data).toUpperCase());
    data = data.plusMonths(1); // somar 1 mês
}
```

Outra alternativa é obter a data atual e extrair somente o mês, obtendo um [`java.time.Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html), que por sua vez possui o [método `plus`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#plus-long-) para somar meses:

```
Month mes = LocalDate.now().getMonth();
int quantidadeMeses = 3;
Locale local = new Locale("pt", "BR");
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM", local);
for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeMeses; i++) {
    System.out.println(fmt.format(mes).toUpperCase());
    mes = mes.plus(1); // somar 1 mês
}
```

E neste caso, também seria possível usar o método [`getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-), em vez de usar um `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
Month mes = LocalDate.now().getMonth();
int quantidadeMeses = 3;
Locale local = new Locale("pt", "BR");
for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeMeses; i++) {
    System.out.println(mes.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, local).toUpperCase());
    mes = mes.plus(1); // somar 1 mês
}
```

---

Se você ainda não usa Java 8, pode usar o [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), que possui as mesmas classes já mencionadas (`LocalDate`, `DateTimeFormatter`, etc) e funciona basicamente do mesmo jeito. A diferença é que elas estão no pacote `org.threeten.bp` (ao invés de `java.time`). O *backport* é compatível com JDK 6 e 7.

---

Caso ainda esteja preso ao Java 5 e queira usar algo melhor que `Date` e `Calendar`, uma alternativa é o [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (embora este seja um projeto considerado "encerrado", já que no seu site [há um aviso](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/#Support) indicando isso e recomendando o uso do `java.time`)

O Joda-Time possui classes com nomes similares ao `java.time`, embora não seja 100% igual. As classes ficam no pacote `org.joda.time`, segue um exemplo similar ao código anterior:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

...
LocalDate date = new LocalDate();
Locale local = new Locale("pt", "BR");
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM").withLocale(local);
int quantidadeMeses = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeMeses; i++) {
    System.out.println(fmt.print(date).toUpperCase());
    date = date.plusMonths(1);
}
```

---

Mais sobre o `java.time` pode ser visto [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052).

Comment: Eu quero apenas 3 letras mesmo, o problema é que sempre mostra o "DEZ", quando eu queria que mostrasse "SET", "OUT" E "NOV" no caso, que seria esse mês e os dois subsequentes

Comment: @EltonTozatto Entendi, atualizei a resposta

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou como eu queria. Vlw mesmo!!

Comment: hoje implementei utilizando o java.time que você recomendou e funcionou perfeitamente, fora que ficou mais prático do que a primeira lógica que tinha utilizado. Vlws

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver usando Java 8+, sugiro que dê uma lida sobre o `LocalDate`.
Com o `LocalDate` facilmente você consegue fazer o seguinte código.

```
LocalDate hoje = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate proximoMes = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(1);
LocalDate segundoMesAFrente = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(2);
```

Aqui esta o [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) da documentação.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada sobre isso e tentar aplicar dessa forma, obrigado!

Comment: @EltonTozatto Não sei se vc viu, mas eu já tinha colocado essa opção na minha resposta :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo vi aqui, obrigado pela ajuda também, vou ler tudo e implementar aqui de acordo com o que preciso, ajudo bastante